# Store and Open PDFs in ESRI App Studio

Tags: qt, arcgis-ios, arcgis-appstudio

Is it possible to open local PDFs from within ESRI's AppStudio?  I can easily open pdfs and files from web links with "Qt.openUrlExternally('http..." but I need this app to work completely offline.  I've tried the approaches here with no luck:  [Files and folders](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/appstudio/extend-apps/apifilesandfolders.htm)

Ultimately, I would want the AppStudio app to appear in the files app, so I could drop new or existing pdfs there via ITunes.  Is there a trick to getting the app to appear here, then how would I read/open files from that location?

Maybe there is a better approach?